# Как указать правильно заголовок вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

Что делать с вопросами у которых в  заголовке присутствует название языка программирования, ведь по сути он не нужен, есть теги которые это указывают.

Вот пример [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630128/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c-datetime-%D0%BA-ms-sql-datetime), заголовок - `Приведение C# datetime к ms sql datetime` по сути не нуждается в указания `C#`

Comment: В общем и целом уже давно решено: метки из заголовка выпиливать. А вот пример вопроса слабый: в этом конкретном примере я бы оставил заголовок как есть.

Comment: При скролле не нашел этот вопрос, Спасибо!

Comment: Во фразе "Приведение C# datetime к ms sql datetime" C# определенно лишнее. Другое дело, что не стоит заботиться править такую мелкую проблему.